# Return True and stop if first item in list is matches, return false if no item matches

Tags: python, loops

I wrote a function to check a string based on the following conditions:

- Check if any word in the string is in list 1.
- If string in list 1, return position to see if the item next to it in
  the string is in list 2.
- If in list 1 and in list 2, return True.
- Else return False.

The tricky part is that those lists are really long. So to be efficient, the first occurrence in list 2 will return True and move on to the next string.

Below is the code that I have choked up but I doubt it is working as intended. Efficiency is really the key her as well. I tried creating a full combination of list 1 and list 2 and then loop through but it seems a bit insane looping over 100 million times per string.

1st Code:

```
def double_loop(words):
    all_words = words.split()
    indices = [n for n,x in enumerate(allwords) if x in list1]
    if len(indices) != 0:
        for pos in indices[:-1]: 
            if all_words[pos+1] in list2: 
                return True 
#the purpose here is not to continue looking #through the whole list of indices, but end as soon as list2 contains an item 1 position after.
                    break
    else:
        return False
```

I am unsure whether the code above is working based on my logic above. In comparison;

2nd Code:

```
def double_loop(words):
    all_words = words.split()
    indices = [n for n,x in enumerate(allwords) if x in list1]
    if len(indices) != 0:
        indices2 = [i for i in indices[:-1] if all_words[i+1] in list2]
        if len(indices2) != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

has the same run time based on my test data.

I guess the clearer question is, will my first code actually run till it finds the "first" element that meets its criteria and break. Or is it still running through all the elements like the second code.

Comment: "I doubt it is working as intended" <- Which tests fail?

Comment: Hi I am sorry, I should be more precise, the run times are very slow, again I do not know whether that is the right code intended for my purpose.

Comment: That doesn't answer @timgeb's question. How is the code not working in the way you intend?

Comment: What errors are you getting in other words.

Comment: And the code as you presented it doesn't run: `allwords` vs `all_words`.

Comment: Give me a sec guys, sorry its quite late. Will edit my question

Comment: @BoarGules apologies, I am actually using 2 different machines for this.

Comment: Well, potentially a super-quick change is to make `adjs` a `set()` before the check for `in`, if possible.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, I already did that after recalling sets provide faster lookups.

Comment: So, reading your criteria again, the first is actually redundant in the logic (it serves as a filter for an `if` but on its own it means nothing)? Are you open to using `pandas` for this?

Comment: Yea I am creating a function to be applied on my series.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you will achieve the fastest lookup time with a precomputed index. This index is the set of all items of list 1, where the following item is in list 2.

```
# Build index, can be reused
index = set(item1 for i, item1 in enumerate(list1[:-1]) if list1[i+1] in list2)

def double_loop(words):
  return any(word in index for word in words.split())
```

Index lookups will be done in constant time, no matter how long list1 and list2 are. Index building will take longer when list1 and list2 get longer. Note that making list2 a set might speed up index building when list1 is large.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `list1` and `list2` should not be lists but sets. That is because a set lookup is a hash lookup and a list lookup is a linear search.

And you don't need a nested loop.

```
def single_loop(words):
    all_words = words.split()
    for w1, w2 in ((all_words[i],all_words[i+1]) for i in range(len(all_words)-1)):
        if w1 in set1 and w2 in set2:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Surely it's not safe to assume that `allwords` can be converted to a set, `list1` maybe.

Comment: list1 and 2 are sets. Fixed that. For efficiency, I am trying to avoid seeing if all matches in list1[i+1] are in list2. Rather when the left most matches it stops finding for a match.

Comment: Two points. Set lookups are cheap, even for very large sets. And `if w1 in set1 and w2 in set2` only does the `set2` membership test if the `set1` test succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the main list only once by combining your criteria in a single list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
list2 = ['a', 'h', 'e', 'p', 'l', 'o']
set_list2 = set(list2)

check = [item for x, item in enumerate(list1) if item in set_list2 and list2[x+1] == item]
```

If you want the function to short-circuit:

```
def check(list1, list2):
    set_list2 = set(list2)
    for x, item in enumerate(list1):
        if item in set_list2 and list2[x+1] == item:
            return True
    return False

a = check(list1, list2)
```